# Vue.js access parent variable

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, dropzone.js

I have a Vue Component where I load Dropzone.js.
It's not possible to use vue2-dropzone, because it does not allow to be attached to the body.

My component looks like:

```
export default {
    props: [
        'maxsize',
        'csrf',
        'url'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            showUploader: false,
            dropZone: {},

            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: this.url,
                success: function (file, response) {
                    console.log(file.filename + ' ' + response);

                },
                error: function (file, response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    return false;
                },
                dragleave: function () {
                    var dragOver = document.getElementById('dragOver');
                    dragOver.classList.add('hidden');
                    this.showUploader = true;
                }
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.dropZone = new Dropzone(document.body, this.dropzoneOptions);
    },
    methods: {

    }
}
```

I want to change the `showUploader` to `true` on `dragleave` but i don't know how to access the variable. I'm really lost.

Comment: Use an arrow function, it’s related to closures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re using an function () syntax which means that this is within the context of the function, and is unable to access this.showUploader

Change the function to an arrow function and this will resolve the issue

```
export default {
  props: ["maxsize", "csrf", "url"],
  data() {
    return {
      showUploader: false,
      dropZone: {},

      dropzoneOptions: {
        url: this.url,
        success: function (file, response) {
          console.log(file.filename + " " + response);
        },
        error: function (file, response) {
          console.log(response);
          return false;
        },
        dragleave: () => {
          var dragOver = document.getElementById("dragOver");
          dragOver.classList.add("hidden");
          this.showUploader = true; // this.showUploader will access the Vue object
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.dropZone = new Dropzone(document.body, this.dropzoneOptions);
  },
  methods: {},
};
```